# Asp .net core dark mode issue

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core

I made the dark mode toggle in my application by checkbox with simple CSS animation (from the sun to moon) and a javascript function executing at the beginning of the view if the cookie "isDarkMode" value is "true", then I toggle for all classes to dark mode.

The issue appears when I toggle, independently whether light or dark mode and got to the site before, the checkbox status remains in the old state (like on the screenshot) though everything besides it works fine and changes to a set mode. Also toggle mode changes to the proper state after refresh.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn1p6.png)

Another problem is; that at every opening of pages of this site on dark mode there is a momentary blink of light mode.

A toggle of mode looks in cshtml layout:

```
<label class="switch">
   @{
       if (ViewBag.isDarkTheme == "true") 
       {
          <input id="checkBox" onclick="toggleTheme()" type="checkbox" checked="checked" asp-        controller="Posts" asp-action="ChangeDarkTheme" />
       }
       else
       {
          <input id="checkBox" onclick="toggleTheme()" type="checkbox" asp-controller="Posts" asp-      action="ChangeDarkTheme" />
       }
   }
   <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```

What can I do, is there any better solution in ASP?

Comment: Did you try to break you styles into 2 seprarte css files "light mode" and "dark mode" and load one of another based on logic? Because, currently you are loading the page first, then you do an action. But you need to make a decision before the page is loaded.